# How to Install Driver on Android box without using MAKE command?

Tags: android, makefile, windows-xp, box

I am trying to install a touch screen driver for an Android TV-Box. When I connect to the device with the ADB tool, I cannot use the "make" command because of a 'not found' error. Although I have updated my BusyBox version, the problem has not resolved.

For the touchscreen that I bought, the manufacturer gave me a bunch of files (a .c file, a makefile file, a .idc file and a readme file, but I cannot apply them to device since there is no make command. The related part of the readme file is written below.

> " a. Make the bontouchusb-st.c, please use the command line below:
>
> $make kernel_dir="Your linux kernel directory"
>        b. Copy the "bontouchusb-st.ko" to the Android file system's /system/lib/modules directory.
>
> c. Add one line to the Android file system's init.rc, under the "on
>   boot"
>         insmod /system/lib/modules/bontouchusb-st.ko
>
> d. Add one line to the Android file system's ueventd.rc:
>         /dev/bontouch      0666   root    root
>
> e. If android version >= 4.0, Copy the file
>   "Vendor_255e_Product_0001.idc" to the Android file system's
>   /system/usr/idc directory. "

If I can pass part(a) then the remains look easy.

I am using Windows Xp 32-Bit OS.
I am waiting for your response.

Thanks.